# Apex Trigger - Create Multiple Child Records with Basic For Loop

Tags: apex, trigger, loop

Trying to create a trigger, please see use case below. I'm extremely novice so I'm sure the pseudocode might not make perfect sense, but it's as close as I could get.
1: Objects: Account, Opportunity, Quote
2: A handful of Accounts have Record Type = 'Partner'
3: Quote has a custom lookup relationship to Account filtered by 'Partner' Record Type
4: When a User checks a box on an Opportunity, need to create one Quote for EACH 'Partner'Account
5: So 1 Account, 1 Opportunity, and maybe 10 Quote records all under the Opportunity, because there were 10 Accounts flagged as Partners...each Quote is related to each separate Partner Account

Pseudo code:

```
trigger CreateQuotes on Opportunity__c (after insert) {

    List<Accounts> Accounts = new List<Accounts>()
     where Account.RecordType == 'Partner'; 

    for(Opportunity o : trigger.new)

    {
       Quote__c Quote = new Quote__c ();
       Quote.Opportunity = o.id;
       Quote.Name = 'testName'; 

       Quotes__c.add(Quotes)
       //and somehow increment through the above list of Accounts and create 1 Quote related to each Partner Account
    }

 insert Quotes;

}
```

Updated trigger with error: Error: Compile Error: Expression cannot be assigned at line -1 column -1
"

```
trigger CreateQuotes on Opportunity (after insert) {

     List<Account> actList = [select Id from Account where RecordType.DeveloperName = 'Partner']; 

     list<NewQuote__c> quoteList = new list<NewQuote__c>();
     for(Opportunity o : trigger.new)
     {
        NewQuote__c quote = new NewQuote__c ();
        NewQuote__c.Opportunity__r.Id = o.id;
        NewQuote__c.Name = 'testName'; 
        quoteList.add(quote);
        if (o.Needs_Partner_Quotes__c){
           for(Account act: actList){
              quote = new NewQuote__c(Opportunity__c = o.id, Account__c=act.Id, Name='testName');
              quoteList.add(quote);
           }
        }     
     }
     insert quoteList;    
}
```

Comment: You didn't define the variable "quote", so `quote = new NewQuote__c` is trying to assign a variable to a static read-only variable whose full name is `System.Schema.Quote`. You should avoid using the names of objects or classes as variables until you get a feel for how it affects code. Instead, you could use `NewQuote__c quoteRecord = new NewQuote__c(...)`

Answer (score 1):

Your pseudo-code is actually pretty close. Here's how I'd approach this:

```
trigger partnerQuotes on Opportunity (after insert) {
    Opportunity[] quoted = new Opportunity[0];
    for(Opportunity record: Trigger.new) {
        if(record.Quoted_to_Partners__c) {
            quoted.add(record);
        }
    }
    if(quoted.isEmpty()) {
        return;
    }
    Quote[] newQuotes = new Quote[0];
    Account[] partners = [SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE RecordType.Name='Partner'];
    for(Account partner: partners) {
        for(Opportunity record: quoted) {
            newQuotes.add(new Quote(Partner__c=partner.Id, OpportunityId=record.Id, Name='Partner Quote'));
        }
   }
   insert newQuotes;
}
```

Note that the order is designed to be structured for maximum efficiency (e.g. no wasted queries, or iterating over Trigger.new more than once).

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description this should work:

```
  trigger CreateQuotes on Opportunity__c (after insert) {

     List<Account> actList = [select Id from Account where RecordType = 'Partner']; 

     list<Quote__c> quoteList = new list<Quote__c>();
     for(Opportunity o : trigger.new)
     {
        Quote__c quote = new Quote__c ();
        quote.Opportunity = o.id;
        quote.Name = 'testName'; 
        quoteList.add(quote);
        if (o.NeedsPartnerQuotes__c){
           for(Account act: actList){
              quote = new Quote__c(Account__c=act.Id, Name='testName);
              quote.Opportunity__c = o.Id;
              quoteList.add(quote);
           }
        }     
     }
     insert quoteList;    
}
```

Comment: Thats great thanks. I did basic debugging and added small things like tweaking this: Name='testName) ... cant figure out the error now, I posted error and updated trigger in main post

Comment: Hi @TNSalesforceGuru this `NewQuote__c.Opportunity__r.Id = o.id;`  should be `NewQuote__c.Opportunity__c = o.id;'  When inserting NewQuote__c you should set the id on the custom field API name and not the relationship API name.

Comment: Thanks! Getting this error now: Compile Error: Invalid field initializer: NewQuote__c.Opportunity__c at line 14 column 45

Comment: Check that the API fieldname for your Opportunity reference on NewQuote__c is Opportunity__c.  If not then correct the name.  If it is correct then set the value outside of the initializer statement at line 14.  I updated my code to illustrate.